# Oracle 11 query functions default value

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

Is there any way to select the default value a procedure/function has for a specific parameter in the procedure/function ?
user_arguments has a field called default_value (long) but I do not see any value in the field.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation says, it is not available yet.

> `DEFAULT_VALUE`    `LONG`      Reserved for future use

[ALL_ARGUMENTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1014.htm)

**Bug:183707  PLSQL COMPILE DOES NOT POPULATE DEFAULT ARGUMENT COLUMNS IN ARGUMENT$**